# Quiet or you die! Hold still or I'll kill you! - present vs. future tense?

Tags: future-tense, present-tense

What is the difference between the future and present tense in the following sentences? Which tense is more preferred?

> Quiet or you die!
>
> Quiet or you'll die!

And

> Hold still or I kill you!
>
> Hold still or I'll kill you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has often been pointed out on ELL, [English only really has two tenses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7703/126) (past, and "not-past"), so there's really no "grammatical rule" in play here. It's more a matter of idiomatic preferences.

One alternative phrasing I didn't give in the above link is *"If you cancel, I go instead"*. Without more context, that version might look slightly odd, but in some cases present tense is actually *preferred* for the "consequential/subsequent action". Consider, for example,...

> *When you die you go to heaven* [(2370 hits in Google Books)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22when%20you%20die%20you%20go%20to%20heaven%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)
>    *When you die you **will** go to heaven* [(1690 hits)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22when%20you%20die%20you%20go%20to%20heaven%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22when%20you%20die%20you%20will%20go%20to%20heaven%22&oq=%22when%20you%20die%20you%20will%20go%20to%20heaven%22&gs_l=serp.3...4474.5667.0.5980.5.5.0.0.0.0.145.386.4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.19.psy-ab.3WZWWYNnjYE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.d2k&fp=c030e09ea1435dc8&biw=1204&bih=899)

---

It's not easy to identify general principles about when native speakers tend *not* to use the modal ***will*** to indicate "future tense" - but it's certainly true that overall we *do* use it more often that not.

I think ***will*** is less likely to be used in contexts where the speaker wants to emphasise the *equivalence* of two actions (since the first one is invariably already expressed in present tense). Thus, for example,...

> *Blink and you lose* [(63 hits)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22blink%20and%20you%20lose%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)
>    *Blink and you **will** lose* [(0 hits)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22blink%20and%20you%20lose%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22blink%20and%20you%20will%20lose%22&oq=%22blink%20and%20you%20will%20lose%22&gs_l=serp.3...5625.7876.0.8172.5.5.0.0.0.0.85.378.5.5.0....0...1c.1.19.psy-ab.RfJv4ZqIGKw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.d2k&fp=c030e09ea1435dc8&biw=1204&bih=899)

It's worth noting that ***will*** also suggests volition and/or inevitability. To some extent, my examples can be seen as "statements". But OP's examples are more likely to be uttered as "threats", in which context ***will*** is much more likely to be included. In the final analysis though, it's normally just a stylistic choice.

Comment: I still don't get that "English has only two tenses" thing. Also in Italian I could use the Simple Present for something that I will do in the future, but Italian is not said to have just past and not-past tenses. For example, it is perfectly idiomatic to say _Domani vado a Roma_ ("Tomorrow I go to Rome."), but nobody says that Italian doesn't have a future tense. In the same way, the translation of "When you die you go to heaven." is _Quando muori vai in paradiso._ (without future tense).

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I'm not great at the terminology, but I think *I walk* and *I am walking* are just "moods", not different "tenses" as such. And either of them can be preceded by, for example, *Tomorrow*, because they can just as easily apply to the future as to the present. You can use "helper" auxiliary verbs like *will* and *shall* to convey "future", but they often have other connotations, and there's no way to "inflect" a variant of the ***primary*** verb to convey future.

Comment: _Moods_ are, for example, the indicative and the imperative moods. Simple Present and Present Continuous are tenses. In Italian, the future tense can be used to speak of something I am willing to do (e.g. _Andrò da mio cugino._, which means "I will to go my cousin's."), in the same way it happens in English. I don't see any difference between Italian and English, in that expect, but nobody says Italian doesn't have a future tense only because the future tense is used also for other purposes, and Simple Present is used to refer to future events.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I'm probably not the best person to convince you, if you disagree with the idea that *English only has **past** and **non-past** tenses*. I'm sure [John Lawler](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110287/improper-expressions-of-the-future-progressive#comment223755_110287) and [StoneyB](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110287/improper-expressions-of-the-future-progressive#comment223718_110288) are better equipped than me to make the case.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis: I think the big difference arises because **WHEN [subject1+verb1], [subject2+verb2]** very explicitly *equates* the two actions, which encourages us to use the same tense. In an imperative like **[You] do this OR I do that** there's more of a sense that "you doing this" is a current (or very near future) action, whereas "me doing that" is in the more distant future (or never, if the threat works). Thus "...or I **will** do that" is far more natural, which to me makes most/all present-tense versions at least slightly "odd".

Comment: Is it just me, or does "Hold still or I kill you!" sound more like broken English than "Quiet or you die!" I think the clause, "I kill you" is just odd itself. The only scenarios I can imagine this is (a) a foreigner saying it: "I kill you now" or (b) A crazed person saying "I kill you, I kill you, I kill you!" during an (actual or metaphorical) act of killing. On the other hand, "Quiet or I kill you" doesn't sound as bad. Maybe it's due to the length of time required to be "Quiet" vs. "Hold still". The latter is a continuing action which doesn't couple well with the simple present. (@J.R.)

Answer (score 1):

Since the killing would take place in the future, I think it's best to include the *will*.

Also, if I was interested in strict and proper grammar, I'd probably change the first one to:

> *Be quiet or you'll die!*

That said, kidnappers, carjackers, bank robbers, and hostage takers who make these remarks are normally rather jacked up on adrenaline when they make such threats, and therefore don't tend to worry too much about correct verb tense, so you might find either of your alternatives in a book or movie script.

Comment: So, is present tense in this case just a result of careless speech?

Comment: I don't know if I'd go that far. They are both understandable. I think the first one ("..or you die!") sounds a little more natural and a little less "careless" than the second ("or I kill you!"), but I'm having trouble figuring out why that's the case. I'll be interested to read what others say.

Comment: @stillenat I guess that in some cases using less words is perfectly normal; for example, a soldier on the battle field would probably say "You OK?" to another soldier, instead of "Are you OK?"

Comment: @J.R. The first sounds more natural to me too. As a long shot I would suggest that this is so because it approximates to _if-sentences_ that use the present tense in both clauses when talking about natural laws or inevitable consequences: _If you put wood on water, it floats. If iron is exposed to air and water, it rusts_. So, a natural consequence of you talking is you dying. In the second case, it's more like a threat than a natural consequence, so the future tense is used.

Comment: @Shoe: I'd already posted my answer before reading your last comment. But seeing it now, I absolutely agree with your last two sentences, obviously!

Comment: As JR says, I wouldn't expect a violent maniac to have carefully-phrased sentences. "I would like to take this opportunity to request that all of you be quiet. I'm afraid that if you don't, I will have to impose undesirable consequences, which may include violent death." Well, it might work for a movie, but I doubt criminals often talk that way in real life.

Comment: @Jay: I don't think that would even work in a movie! It's hilarious, though... it reminds me of a friend of mine who would talk that way often. I remember one time, when he was hungry: "I'm dying to get my hands on some organic matter, so I can stuff it down my oral cavity." For some reason, he could get away with the eloquence, but I think that's a rare exception.

Comment: @J.R. I think the movie would not be credible; maybe a parody could use such a verbose phrase, but not a movie that pretends narrating something really happened.

Comment: To the extent that this is a serious conversation: I was thinking that movies often give villains strange idiosyncrasies to make them more entertaining, like wearing colorful costumes or leaving some distinctive "calling card" at every crime scene or having some peculiar style of speech. Most real-life criminals are far less entertaining than the Joker or Lex Luthor et al.