# "were to precede" instead of "preceded": cannot parse this sentence structure

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions, auxiliary-verbs

Suppose this sentence

> It would be helpful if you **were to precede** the report  with  an introduction.

I just cannot figure out why in this sentence, author used "were to precede". In my opinion shouldn't author use "preceded" instead?

If this sentence is already correct, how can we parse it? What's its tense?

Comment: "were to" has a different usage of only "were" . So you should study on "were to" or "was to". http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15276/use-of-were-to-in-english-grammar

Comment: http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/wereto.html

Comment: @Murat Thanks very much, your second link was very helpful for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, using "proceed" is plain wrong. The statement says that putting an introduction before (*preceding*, in front of) the report would be helpful. Using "proceed" instead would be a typo, introducing gibberish.

Comment: @A.Beth: Ooops! You're quite right. Comment deleted. But it *is* a "subjunctive" usage.

Comment: That, I'll agree with! (...should I delete my correction-comment or leave it as "history"?)

Comment: Sentences don't have tense, verbs do.  The two finite verbs (*would* and *were*) are both past tense.  *Precede* and *be* are not tensed.  (There is no *was-were* realis-irrealis contrast to be made here, since the subject of *were* is *you*, so that topic can be ignored here.)

Comment: @@A.Beth: In theory the mods will probably delete most of our comments here eventually. But the comment that I deleted myself had this link to the relevant [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) page: *A **compound past subjunctive** form is made with were (the past subjunctive of **be**) followed by a verb's **to-infinitive** (corresponding to indicative forms like **I was to own**). For example: **(if) I were to own***. Unless someone (you, for example) makes that point in an *answer*, I'd expect *this* comment to be kept indefinitely.

Comment: The example sentence is fine as is. (Though, your suggestion would also work.) In *CGEL*, page 206, [69.ii] "*If she was/were to come home now, we'd be in real trouble.* … In remote conditionals *be* generally serves merely to reinforce the remote modality (combining harmonically with the preterite tense or irrealis mood): [ii] is interpreted as 'If she came home now, we'd be in real trouble'." -- Which in your case, your example has the meaning: *It would be helpful if you preceded the report with an introduction* (which is the same as your proposed alternative).

Answer (score 1):

*It would be helpful if you were to precede the report with an introduction.*

The sentence is correct.

The meaning of the sentence is that it would help if the report-writer added an introduction to the beginning of the report. (So the introduction would *precede* the actual report.)

As mentioned by @murat in the comments, [this other post is of interest.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15276/use-of-were-to-in-english-grammar)

Essentially, this is the [subjunctive mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood), which is used primarily for hypothetical situations. From the linked Wikipedia article:

> typically used to express various states of unreality such as wish, emotion, possibility, judgment, opinion, necessity, or action that has not yet occurred.