# If we tell them the truth they wouldn't believe us

Tags: conditionals, clauses

> If we **tell** them the truth they wouldn't believe us

Is this construction correct in English? I mean, for conditional sentences, the rule is *If+past tense/would +infinitive*, but here, can we also use the present in the "if" clause?

The meaning, as I see, can be "We tell them the truth and they still don't want to believe us"

Comment: Maybe if you used the archaic “wouldst”. I’m not sure what you’re aiming for with the *apostrophe-s*.

Comment: Sorry, it it Wouldn't. Question is if "tell" is the right tense

Comment: I think this question fits better in the [ell.se] section and have voted to migrate the question there.

Comment: “*If we tell*” and “*If we told*” can both convey a sense of future telling in your example.

Comment: Most idiomatic is "told"->"wouldn't" and "tell"->"won't".  Though there are arguments that can be made that the others are not technically improper.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that this is perhaps an example where a *conditional tense* should be used:

> If we **were to** tell them the truth, they wouldn't believe us.
>   Meaning: Even *if* we told them the truth, they wouldn't believe us.

Note that here "were" is **not** being used as *past* tense, but as a *conditional* tense.
Further details of using *were to* in this way are given in the following references:

- Were to in the Present : https://www.englishpage.com/conditional/wereto.html
- How to use Were to : https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/how-use-were
- Use of “were to” in English grammar : https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15276/use-of-were-to-in-english-grammar

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to keep the tenses the same throughout the sentence.

> If we tell them the truth they will not believe us

> If we told them the truth they wouldn't believe us